# Intereseting Fork/Join or Divide and Conquer Examples

Tags: java-7, divide-and-conquer, fork-join

We want to showcase the new JDK7 Fork/Join Framework on a conference workshop. For this we are currently searching for an interesting example what can be done with the framework.

There are obvious ones like sorting or matrix calculations but are there more interesting ones which people like to work on. For example we found Image blurring at the java site or maybe weather forecasting or something like that?

It would be good if the domain is not too complex so the problems can be solved in a days time.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Any ideas or experiences?

Answer (score 1):

I think cellular automata make great examples, like Conway's life (at least that is what I did on a workshop, and it worked).